# How do I disable broadcast notifications on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, notifications

Twitter recently started sending me purple broadcast notifications when users I follow start livestreaming. I find these to be annoying and would like to turn them off.

**How do I turn off broadcast notifications on Twitter?**

[image: user started a broadcast]